# Unable to run System Log on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: permissions, syslog

I am having a difficult time to run syslog GUI. I added a new filter in the System Log. What I did is: click the button at the top right of the GUI window (the button with a gear icon). Then, click the menu item filter-> New -> filled with a filter name (the filter name is words with a space character separated)and a key word of the log I would like the see -> click ok to finish to create the filter.

After that, the system log crashed. Since then, I could not run the syslog gui anymore. Every time I try to start the application, it automatically closed directly.

Here is the log file content related the syslog. It seem KLogPermitNonKernaelFacility is unable to run. Anyone knows how to fix the problem?

**[Edit 2.1]**
After I use:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

I found everytime I try to run syslog, the kernel gives me:

```
traps: gnome-system-lo[20589] trap int3 ip:7f83223aba6b sp:7ffc2e3b3730 error:0
```

**[What I tried]**
I tried to uninstall rsyslog and reinstall

```
apt-get autoremove rsyslog
```

and then do

```
apt-get install rsyslog
```

**[Edit 2]**
Did an uninstall with purge as  MicroParsec suggested. Still unable to start the log application

```
$:/var/log$ sudo apt-get remove --purge rsyslog 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  rsyslog*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
After this operation, 1,328 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 215216 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing rsyslog (8.16.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Purging configuration files for rsyslog (8.16.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
$:/var/log$ sudo apt-get purge rsyslog
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'rsyslog' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
$:/var/log$ sudo apt-get install rsyslog
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  rsyslog-mysql | rsyslog-pgsql rsyslog-doc rsyslog-gnutls rsyslog-gssapi rsyslog-relp
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  rsyslog
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/365 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,328 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package rsyslog.
(Reading database ... 215156 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../rsyslog_8.16.0-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking rsyslog (8.16.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu7) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up rsyslog (8.16.0-1ubuntu3) ...

Creating config file /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf with new version
The user `syslog' is already a member of `adm'.
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu7) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
```

**[edit 3]**

After edited `sudo gedit /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`

from

```
daemon.*;mail.*;\
    news.err;\
    *.=debug;*.=info;\
    *.=notice;*.=warn   |/dev/xconsole
```

to

```
daemon.*;mail.*;\
    news.err;\
    *.=debug;*.=info;\
    *.=notice;*.=warn   
#|/dev/xconsole
```

The kernel still spit `gnome-system-lo[21384] trap int3 ip:7f817444aa6b sp:7fff2713fb00 error:0` and refuse to start syslog viewer.

Thanks in advance.

Rong

Comment: Could you [edit] and be more specific about what you did that caused this please?

Comment: hello Zanna, I add the details that how I create the filter. Thanks

Comment: don't use `autoremove` to uninstall. `autoremove` uninstalls unneeded packages. `remove` and `purge` uninstall the package in the second argument. `purge` removes all config as well.

Comment: @ MicroParsec thanks for you suggestion, but the syslog is still not working :(

Comment: Are the permissions of `/var/log/kern.log` `syslog:adm`?

Comment: What I can see is:  `-rw-r-----  1 syslog            adm    1575635 Aug 19 11:38 kern.log` , so I think yes, kern.log's owner is syslog:adm

Comment: Alright, I had to ask because of https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2221626 , but I soon realized their cause of problems was a distribution upgrade, which your case is not. Try what he said in his post though, commenting out the xconsole lines in /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf . 

I'm not sure if this is an actual fix or a bodge, but at least your logger will work again.

Comment: Thanks for you help MicroParsec, could you please see the edit3?